# Py2App Placing PIL Dylibs in Zip file

Tags: python, code-signing, py2app

I have an python application that uses the Python Imaging Library (PIL) and is packaged using Py2app. Numpy dylibs are found in the app contents directory:

```
demo.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/numpy/.dylibs/libgcc_s.1.dylib
```

where they can be searched for and signed but PIP dylibs are inside a `python3.8.zip` file

```
demo.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.zip -> ./PIL/.dylibs/libfreetype.6.dylib
```

where one would have to unzip, sign, and rezip them. Why does this happen and how do I prevent it so that I don't have to treat it different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`py2app` implements special handling of certain packages via a mechanism called ["recipes"](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html).  It comes with built-in recipes for certain packages including `numpy`, which is why numpy is excluded from the `.zip` file.  ([Here's the built-in numpy recipe.](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/py2app/blob/master/py2app/recipes/numpy.py))

In addition to the built-in recipes, you can [define your own recipes](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#developing-recipes) for py2app to use.  Just define a class that has a `check` method, and monkey-patch it as an attribute onto `py2app.recipes`:

```py
# In setup.py

class PIL_recipe:
    def check(self, cmd, mf):
        m = mf.findNode("PIL")
        if m is None or m.filename is None:
            return None

        # Exclude from site-packages.zip
        return {"packages": ["PIL"]}

py2app.recipes.PIL = PIL_recipe()

...

setup(...)
```

If you need to do this with several libraries, you can generalize this trick so that it doesn't hard-code the name of the package:

```
class ExcludeFromZip_Recipe(object):
    def __init__(self, module):
        self.module = module

    def check(self, cmd, mf):
        m = mf.findNode(self.module)
        if m is None:
            return None

        # Don't put the module in the site-packages.zip file
        return {"packages": [self.module]}

for module in ['PIL', 'skimage', 'sklearn', 'jsonschema']:
    setattr( py2app.recipes, module, ExcludeFromZip_Recipe(module) )
```

Disclaimer: This is how I've solved this problem in the past.  But I'm not sure why your zip file is named `python3.zip` instead of `site-packages.zip`.